# AWS Greengrass intermittent message loss

Tags: amazon-web-services

We are running AWS Greengrass on a RHEL 7.6 machine. We run lambdas on the local greegrass that start executing when a MQTT message is passed from cloud to the local greengrass via MQTT subscription.

While testing this flow, we have noticed that the messages sent from IOT cloud are intermittently not being received by the local lambdas.

When we restart the greengrass daemon, the messages are received for a while, but after some time, the messages are not being received.

Can you let me know what can be the issue in this case.